# How to evaluate expressions which involve derivatives and evaluations of functions in a specific case, via a condition?

Tags: functions, functional-style

I have an expression involving the derivative of an arbitrary function r_0

```
c0 =  Derivative[1][Subscript[r, 0]]
```

Later I must replace r_0 by several specific functions, derivate, and also apply evaluations of the function, at x_A=1; I don't use just x, since there are other functions and variables involved. One function is \frac{a_0 x_A}{x_A b_{0,A}+1}. I tried to use pure function substitution:

```
    cr = Subscript[r, 0] -> 
        Subscript[a, 0] #/(1 + Subscript[b, 0, A] #) &[Subscript[x, A]]
c0 //. cr
```

The output  in latex form

$$\left(\frac{a_0 x_A}{x_A b_{0,A}+1}\right)' $$

suggests that Mathematica almost understood that I want to differentiate a function, but it didn't do it.

I also tried Indexed, but this seems to change nothing

```
c0 = Derivative[1][Indexed[r, 4]]
cr = Indexed[r, 4] -> Subscript[a, 0] #/(1 + Subscript[b, 0, A] #) &[
  Subscript[x, A]]
c0 //. cr
```

Comment: I have a hard time following your question here. What would be the desired outcome of the replacement at the bottom? Also, have you tried replacing the `Subscript`ed variables with indexed ones (e.g. `x[a]`, `x[c]`), which are often easier to use? Remember also that C has a built in meaning and may give you trouble down the line.

Comment: I added the output in latex form, I hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Subscript[r,1], Mathematica has invented the partial Derivative[n] wrt. to position of any symbol, including Subscript, Export or Quit

```
   Derivative[1, 0][Quit]["Hello", "not now"]
```

$$\text{Quit}^{(1,0)}(\text{Hello},\text{not now})$$

Use Indexed[r,1] instead. But Indexed doesn't accept index 0 and multi-indices as a single list, only.

If you want to replace an abstract derivative, you have to use  forms like ( of cause with :> )

Derivative[1][f_] :> (Derivative[1][g]&)
in case f has no explicitely known derivative, or
HoldPattern[D[f,x]]:>D[expr,x]
in case to suppress evaluation of D[f,x] to another form as given in input.

Often its easier to replace directly evaluted derivatives

Derivative[n,m,0___][f_]:> (g&)

Comment: Thanks,  I also tried Indexed, but this seems to change nothing. And this does need double indexes as well